# Filter one data table based on conditions from another table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a Main data table having 40 columns and 1000 records . and a criteria table having 9 columns and very few records may be 20-30 . 
for every column in **criteria table**  there is a corresponding column in **main table**

so here is the problem , 
For every Row in criteria sheet , i will have to  take that Row then i will filter the main table  according to this criteria.

in other words , 
for every row is "criteria table " there will be a set of rows returned from the main table.
now , there are many ways to do this , 
what i am looking for is something using LINQ or similar concept and can i do this in one line ?

Criteria sheet will look like this , 
[image]

Comment: Sure. You can use Linq, something like: `dim filtered = [DataTable].AsEnumerable().Where(function(r) r("Brand").Equals("MICHELIN") AndAlso r("CAIs").ToString().Contains("606056")).CopyToDataTable()`, or you can use the DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter and set similar conditions: `[DataTable].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Brand LIKE '%MICHELIN%' AND CAIs = 606056"`. Of course, you take those Columns names and values from the *Criteria* table.

Comment: i get what you are saying , so this needs to  be done for every row in criteria sheet. 
so how to i merge the results ? 
for each row in criteria table : 
             one liner . 
now one liner will either return list of data rows or a data table. but i want to merge results in to one DT

Comment: [DataTable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge) Method.

Comment: what i am looking for is en effective method. in other words , While i exit from for each loop of criteria sheet , i should have a filtered DT from "main sheet". 
i just want to avoid the technique of storing this DTs in to an AL or Array during every iteration and then later again use the AL or Array to merge and make a single DT.

Comment: i get your point. but this one liner will fetch all the columns of the main table based on the conditions i just need 29 columns out of 42 columns of the main table. can i specify it ?

Comment: Filters work on Rows collections, not on Columns. If you don't need some Columns after a filter is applied and you have merged the results in a new DataTable (if that's what you actually want to do), you can remove them. Otherwise you have to operate server-side.

Comment: @Jimi Please!!! I am often helped by your comments but my old eyes have trouble reading the code in a comment. Also, questions go without an accepted answer when your excellent comment can't be accepted. Future readers may ignore this question because it appears there is no answer. It really is an answer.

Comment: @Jimi please give the same thing as answer , i will close this thread. and let me thank you in your answer :)

Comment: @Mary, seetharaman: I'd gladly post an answer, if more details on the operation were available. For example, do I know which Columns provide a filter in the *Criteria* table? All Fields that are not `null`? Are they `null` or could be an empty string? Do I know the types of these Columns (they're strong-typed) or should I treat them all as strings? Do these Columns in *Criteria* have the same names in the DataTable(s) they should filter? Which Columns should be removed in *final product*? Are these DataTables part of the same DataSet, so I should use relations instead? And so on...

Comment: First of all my sincere apology for getting back to the same thread again. i did not get a chance to work on this , i got other things completly occupying me, now i  started working on this again. i am planning to answer questions raised by @jimi for a month now ! i got the time

Comment: Here are the answers :
1. Which columns provide a filter with data table ?
     All columns , but some times some columns may be empty . 
2. Al feilds that are not Null ? Yes As i mentioned above 
3. Are they NUll or could be empty string ? Empty string 
4. do these columns in criteria table share same names as in the main table ? Yes . 
5.which columns to be removed in the final product ? as i said i need only 29 out of 42. i shall give the details later.
6.are these tables are part of same dateset ? nope , these 2 are result of reading 2 different excel sheets. @Mary.Jimmi am i clear?

Comment: @Jimi my answers are ok ?